# Execute code after Excel Download in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, excel, webforms

I'm having a piece of code which downloads excel of Invalid records after Import.

I want to refresh a grid after this kind of partial successful import. But, code after excel auto download is not executing.

```
Response.Clear();
                                    Response.ClearHeaders();
                                    Response.ClearContent();
                                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + PathToExcelFile);
                                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
                                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                                    Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
                                    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
                                    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

I had found that Response.Flush() will throw an Thread Abort exception. Hence changed it to CompleteRequest(). But, still no luck.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot. You can either download an Excel or update the UI. Not both. If you want both you need to use Ajax or open the Excel download in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file name/path etc. to ViewState variables, then call window.open to a separate download.aspx page which processes the downloading of the file. In the Download page reference the ViewState variables you previously set. In the original (not the download) page you can execute what ever code you like after the window.open call.